# JavaFX ComboBox with ONE editable item

Tags: java, javafx

I'd like to have a ComboBox with following options:

(combobox employment:)
- Education
- Automotive
- (...)
- OTHER   <-- editable

If user selects "other", he could edit the item in the ComboBox but all the other options would be non-editable.
Is that possible or should I just display additional TextField when user selects "other"?

Answer (score 1):

There is the option to make a ComboBox editable:

```
combobox.setEditable(true);
```

You can only make all entries editable with this function though.
Read more at: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/combo-box.htm

As far as I know you can only add Strings to the ObservableList which contains the content of your Combobox. Therefore you can not add a Node (in this case a Textfield).

Same goes for the ChoiceBox, if you add a TextField there (which is technically possible) but you will only get the .toString displayed when you actually use it.

Therefore you are probably best of creating a seperate field.

Just as an idea: You can quickly make a popup window when the user clicks "Other", in which whatever other is entered. Then, when you close the window or click enter or whatever, this value is added to the ObservableList. Would make it look nicer I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Use this example:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package comboboxeditable;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author reegan
 */
public class ComboBoxEditable extends Application {

    Node sub;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ComboBox mainCombo = new ComboBox(listofCombo());
        Button  save = new Button("Save");
        sub = new ComboBox(listofCombo());
        HBox root = new HBox(20);
        root.getChildren().addAll(mainCombo, sub,save);

        mainCombo.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                if (newValue == "Others") {
                    sub = new TextField();
                } else {
                    sub = new ComboBox(listofCombo());
                }
                root.getChildren().remove(1);
                root.getChildren().add(1, sub);
            }
        });
        save.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println(mainCombo.getValue());
                if(sub.getClass() == ComboBox.class) {
                    ComboBox sub1 = (ComboBox)sub;
                    System.out.println(sub1.getValue());
                } else {
                    TextField field = (TextField)sub;
                    System.out.println(field.getText());
                }
            }
        });


        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public ObservableList listofCombo() {
        ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.add(String.valueOf("Hello" + i));
        }
        list.add("Others");
        return list;
    }

}
```